# Writing an Erlang timeit function

Tags: erlang

I want to write an Erlang `timeit` function (like the Python module) as a learning exercise that tells me for how long a particular function ran. Problem is, I'm pretty noob in Erlang and can't figure out how this is to be done.

Attempt 1 (try to make an accumulator):

```
timeit_acc(T, start, F) -> timeit_acc({os:timestamp(), T}, finish, F);
timeit_acc({T1, T2}, finish, F) -> element(T1, 2) - element(T2, 2).
timeit(F) -> timeit_acc(os:timestamp(), start, F).
```

This of course doesn't work as I couldn't figure out where to actually call the function `F`. I'm also very sure that's not the only problem with this code. :P

Attempt 2 (trying to make a function execute several statements, like Python):

```
timeit(F)->
    {M, S, MS} = os.timestamp(),
    F,
    {M2, S2, MS2} = os.timestamp(),
    {M2 - M1, S2- S1, MS2- MS1}.
```

I was pretty hopeful of the second attempt, but ran into the following brick-wall:

```
79> c(timeit).
timeit.erl:11: syntax error before: '.'
timeit.erl:3: function timeit/1 undefined
error
```

Now that I think about it, I'm also wondering how can I handle the function `F` when it can have different number of arguments . . . Can somebody please tell me how this can be done? And of course, a little bit of explanation will be very nice.

**==== Update ====**

Following the suggestions received in comments, the new version of the function is:

```
timeit(F) ->
    {M, S, MS} = os:timestamp(),
    Val = F(),
    {M2, S2, MS2} = os:timestamp(),
    {{M2 - M, S2 - S, MS2 - MS}, Val}.
```

However, now I'm not sure how to use it. I tried to profile the `erlang:time/0` function but failed:

```
109> c(timeit).
{ok,timeit}
110> timeit:timeit(time).
** exception error: bad function time
```

Comment: is it an exercise, or a need you have? If you just need the function you can use: `timer:tc(Module,Function,ArgList)` which will return a tuple `{Time,Value}` where `Time` is the elapsed time in ms, and `Value` the normal return of the function.

Comment: @Pascal It's an exercise. From Joe's book. :-)

Comment: your second attempt is promising, I think you should convert the time-stamp in ms before the subtraction (to avoid carry propagation problems) take care that M1, S1, MS1 are undefined, and look at the way to execute the function F (look at apply/3)

Comment: @Pascal Thanks! So, what I'm doing is not a syntax error, after all! I thought separating statements with commas was a sure error, because all function bodies I encountered so far were single-statement magic spells. I will look at `apply` and report in a while.

Comment: Oh and the syntax to call a function is `os:timestamp()` :o)

Comment: @Pascal Oh, damn! Didn't notice that! x-)

Comment: To pass `erlang:time/0` as an argument to your function, prefix it with `fun` and include the arity: `timeit:timeit(fun erlang:time/0)`

Comment: @legoscia Superb! Care to explain why it's so? I don't mind reading a tutorial or something is the explanation is longish. And once again, many thanks for all the advice and help!

Comment: @dotslash The short version is that Erlang functions are identified by three things: the module, the function name, and the number of arguments. When you pass the atom `time` to your function, you have only provided the function name; the other two pieces are missing. Longer explanation here: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/higher-order-functions

Comment: @legoscia Ah! It completely skipped my mind that `time` by itself is an atom. And I guess `fun` means "make function" or something like that. I had come across that link before; it's daunting, to say the least. For now your explanation will do. :-)

Comment: @legoscia Hey, sorry but I'm now stuck on how to profile functions with arguments? All of these gives me syntax error: `timeit:timeit(fun erlang:element(1,T)/2).`, `timeit:timeit(fun erlang:element(1,T)).`, `timeit:timeit(fun erlang:element/2, [1, T]).` :(

Comment: You need to specify the function and the arguments separately, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38591299/113848).

Comment: @legoscia Hmmm. In that case it looks like that answer is what solves it for me and I should be accepting that one instead. Please don't mind. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt is very close.
Try using this,

```
timeit(F,Args) ->
    {MS, S, US} = os:timestamp(),
    erlang:apply(F,Args),
    {MS2, S2, US2} = os:timestamp(),
    {MS2-MS,S2-S,US2-US}.
```

**Note:** [`erlang:apply/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#apply-2) allows you to run a function with a list of arguments. In the code above `Args` should be a list with all the arguments for function `F`. If you for example want to run a function with 3 arguments `Args` will be `[Arg1,Arg2,Arg3]`. (This includes zero arguments too). See examples below.

**Examples:**

```
3> testit:timeit(fun(X) -> X+X end, [5]).
{0,0,7}
4> testit:timeit(fun lists:append/2, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).
{0,0,1}
5> testit:timeit(fun() -> io:format("Fun with no args~n",[]) end, []).
Fun with no args
{0,0,688}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that restrict me to passing the arguments as one unit? I don't think this implementation will allow me to time, say, the `tuple_to_list()` function, will it?

Comment: It does not restrict you. You can run any function with it. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

In attempt 2, your function calls look like `os.timestamp`, with a dot between the module name and the function name like in Python, but in Erlang that should be a colon instead: `os:timestamp`.

---

As of Erlang 18, an alternative to `os:timestamp` is `erlang:monotonic_time`. If I understand [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html) correctly, the "Erlang monotonic time" is probably the kind of time stamp you want to use to measure time elapsed during a function call.

From the [`timer:tc` source code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-19.0/lib/stdlib/src/timer.erl#L157-L169):

```
tc(F) ->
    T1 = erlang:monotonic_time(),
    Val = F(),
    T2 = erlang:monotonic_time(),
    Time = erlang:convert_time_unit(T2 - T1, native, micro_seconds),
    {Time, Val}.
```

`erlang:monotonic_time()` by itself returns a timestamp as an integer in an unspecified "native" time unit.  That's why the call to `erlang:convert_time_unit` is needed, to convert from `native` to `micro_seconds`.  You could also call `erlang:monotonic_time(micro_seconds)` to do the conversion at the point where you get the timestamp.

Comment: A much better answer (and explanation!) but this gives me `** exception error: undefined function erlang:monotonic_time/0`. Why would that be? I'm on R16B03.

Comment: `erlang:monotonic_time` is new (since 18.0, iirc).

Comment: @dotslash Indeed, with R16B03 you need to stick with `os:timestamp`. (R16B03 was released almost three years ago, so it might be time to start looking at upgrading.)

Comment: @legoscia Yes, will upgrade. Last time I checked though, Erlang installation was not quite like `apt-get install xxxx`. Maybe need to look again. Thanks for the suggestion! :-)

Comment: @legoscia I updated my question based on your inputs. Still getting an error when trying to profile the BIF `time`. Please see original post for details and help.

Comment: I wrote basically the same function, but used system_time instead. Is there an advantage to using monotonic time?

Comment: @DonBranson If the system time is changed between the two measurements, you'll get incorrect results. With monotonic time, the Erlang VM makes an effort to get reasonable results even if the clock changes.